# How does this voltage refence work?

Tags: voltage-reference

Regarding the left side of the circuit:

[image]

There is a fixed 1.2V [voltage reference](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm185-1.2-n.pdf?ts=1675040706236&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and a potentiometer for the input.

What could be the purpose of the voltage reference in this case? And what is the purpose of the resistor R1? And how is R1 sized?

Comment: How can we know why someone put a voltage reference there when we don't know what U1 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shunt voltage reference. R1 has to give it enough current for it to work (read the fine [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lm18512fa.pdf)). The current the reference gets is whatever current goes through R1 (use Ohm's law taking the supply and reference voltages into account) minus 1.2V/(R6 + 10k + R3). The reference will also have a maximum current. Ideally you'd want somewhat more than the minimum, perhaps the current at which it is specified.

The op-amp with the ugly symbol is (presumably, since it's cropped) a voltage follower with some compensation allowing it to drive a capacitive load.

As shown the pot would adjust the output reference voltage from about 0 to 109mV (if it's a voltage follower, that is). In any case that will be the input voltage to pin 3 of U1 assuming U1 does not significantly load or otherwise affect it.

Comment: Vs=5V. So the current through R1 is (5V-1.2V)/10k = 0.38mA. And as you wrote the current through the leftmost node is 1.2V/(R6 + 10k + R3) = 0.011mA. That means the current through the LM385 becomes 369μA. But in the datasheet Minimum Operating Current is given as typical 8μA and maximum 15μA. But in our case this current is 369μA. Aren't we exceeding the max ratings for the current?

Comment: At the beginning it says: 10µA to 20mA Operating Range. Does that mean the max current it can handle is 20mA?

Comment: @ty_1917 Well, that's the big print and that's what it means. You need to dig deeper into the real numbers to optimize it. Typically you can ignore the stuff ahead of the tables in a datasheet for serious purposes and the curves at the end are usually just for general guidance too (like interpolation between the hard guarantees in the tables).

Comment: If it doesn't get 15uA it is not guaranteed to work (though it *might* work at less current, it's not guaranteed to *not* work, typically 8uA is enough, but you might get a better or worse unit and they'll consider it meeting specifications). 369uA is well over that so it will work fine even if the tolerances go the wrong way in the resistors, power supply, pot. It's not so much that it wastes too much current or causes much warm-up drift due to self-heating, so not unreasonable. Also 10kΩ is a common value of resistor.